# Why does ccache fail compiler invocation?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, ccache

I have the following clang invocation over cmake, with launcher `ccache`:

Variable `clang="clang.sh"` which forwards everything to `/usr/local/opt/llvm@12/bin/clang++`.

```sh
cd /Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/build/src/cli && 
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.0/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --launcher=/usr/local/bin/ccache 
--tidy="/usr/local/opt/llvm@12/bin/clang-tidy;-header-filter=.;-extra-arg=-Wno-unknown-warning-option;-warnings-as-errors=*;--extra-arg-before=--driver-mode=g++" 
--source=/Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/repo/tests/project/src/cli/main.cpp -- 
"$clang" 
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 
-I/Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/repo/tests/project/src -I/Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/build/src 
-isystem /Users/.../.conan/data/fmt/8.0.1/_/_/package/1b37c9018fa8c082ffdce42c15ed2c2df125254e/include 
-stdlib++-isystem/usr/local/opt/gcc@11/include/c++/11 
-cxx-isystem/usr/local/opt/gcc@11/include/c++/11/x86_64-apple-darwin20 
-L/usr/local/opt/gcc@11/lib/gcc/11 -Wno-unused-command-line-argument 
-stdlib++-isystem/usr/local/opt/gcc@11/include/c++/11 
-cxx-isystem/usr/local/opt/gcc@11/include/c++/11/x86_64-apple-darwin20 
-L/usr/local/opt/gcc@11/lib/gcc/11 -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  
-m64 -stdlib=libstdc++ 
-g 
-arch x86_64 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12.0 
-fPIE 
-stdlib=libstdc++ 
-fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Wcast-align -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Werror -fsanitize=address 
-fsanitize=undefined,bounds -fno-sanitize-recover=undefined,bounds 
-std=c++20 -Winvalid-pch -Xarch_x86_64 
-include/Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/build/src/cli/CMakeFiles/cli.dir/cmake_pch_x86_64.hxx 
-MD -MT src/cli/CMakeFiles/cli.dir/main.cpp.o 
-MF CMakeFiles/cli.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cli.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/repo/tests/project/src/cli/main.cpp
```

That works and compiles. However when I replace `clang=/usr/local/opt/llvm@12/bin/clang++` in the above invocation I get a pretty weird compiler error:

```
clang-12: error: precompiled header '/Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/build/src/cli/CMakeFiles/cli.dir/cmake_pch_x86_64.hxx.pch' 
was ignored because 
'-include /Users/.../.conan/data/base/v1.1.2-54-ge4d704c72c-dirty/demo/testing/build/b89eabddf85eda2e51e68e8ed645dc23f2490817/build/src/cli/CMakeFiles/cli.dir/cmake_pch_x86_64.hxx' 
is not first '-include' [-Werror]
```

Why is that?? It does not make any sense.

Comment: This is definitely going to need an MRE... but I will say that `-Werror` and precompiled headers do not play nicely together. You might want to disable the `-Werror` check for PCH specifically.